# How to import a web assembly code in html

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I am learning the fundamentals of web assembly using rust and I am following [this tutorial](https://austincrim.com/blog/rust-hearts-javascript-write-and-run-your-first-wasm-module). It worked fine for all the things except when importing the web assembly javascript code where it gives this error,

> Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost:8000/pkg/hello_wasm.js”.

I tried disabling all the third party extensions and retried it but I am getting the same  error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello Wasm!</title>
    <script type="module">
      import init, { add } from './pkg/hello_wasm.js'

      await init() // this loads and instantiates our WASM module
      console.log(add(1, 2)) // this calls our compiled Rust function!
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>


 └── App/
    ├── pkg/
    │   ├── hello_wasm_bg.wasm
    │   ├── hello_wasm.js
    │   ├── some _ other _ files
    │   └── index.html
    └── src/
        └── lib.rs
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `index.html` in your `pkg` folder, so when you import the js file as `./pkg/...` it will look for a folder called `pkg` inside of `pkg`. Move `index.html` up a directory (and restart the server from the `App` folder), or change the import to `./hello_wasm.js` for this to work properly.

```
 └── App/
    ├── index.html
    ├── pkg/
    │   ├── hello_wasm_bg.wasm
    │   ├── hello_wasm.js
    │   └── some _ other _ files
    └── src/
        └── lib.rs
```

Comment: Thank you that import error has been solved  but now I am getting this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined`